# How to get View's position inside ViewGroup?

Tags: android, view, position

I have a linear layout and some widgets inside it. How to get position of some widget inside linear layout, so i can then use removeViewAt(int positon) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confused about the `removeViewAt` method.  It is not passed a position of a view, it is passed an index parameter.  This index is the index of the child within the `ViewGroup`.

I don't think you can remove a view using position information.  You would have to write some sort of method that decided which index to remove ***based on*** its positional information.